# How to make "touchscreen" to work on Android from a serial port?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, attiny

My car has a factory 9" touch screen input and there is a video interface that has the touch position (x,y) in a serial format.

Perfect fit for a Raspberry/OrangePi/Tinker Board/etc and I'm wondering how to input this x,y as the touch position for Android.

Depending on the SBC it can be connected in a GPIO pin or in the worst scenario I can use a TTL to USB (or even program one ATTiny85 to do the data conversion).

The question that remains is: how can I configure Android or create a driver to use this data to actual perform the touch?

Answer (score 0):

I figured! Someone already did that with a Teensy 3 and I can replicate the implementation for similar boards: https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=1001891